# On click of image, show/hide (fade-in/out) text+icons overlay

Tags: react-native

I want to develop the following behavior:

*On click of image:*

1. add text/icons overlay onto clicked image
2. clicked image gets faded / darkened a bit

*On subsequent click of same image:*

1. text/icons overlay fades away
2. clicked image is reverted back to normal state

Here is the code so far, for the image with no overlay. I've looked at similar questions but none seem to fit my desired behavior.

```
render() {
    const image = this.props.image
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#D8D8D8",
            width: "100%",
            aspectRatio: 1
          }}
          source={{ uri: image }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step - 1 : Use a flatlsit to render the items.

Step - 2 : Use a touchable opacity to render the items abd inside that add the image.

Step - 3 : On press of the button show or hide the details which can be managed through state. Also pass the index from the flatlist render item and map the index with the details saved in typecasted variable/state

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Think I'm heading in the right direction :)